# Audit IP change on a Windows machine

Tags: windows, audit

I want to get an audit (event in the event viewer) for every change in the IP address (static or DHCP).

I tried setting an audit configuration on the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces`'for set value operation.

When I change the IPAddress in the registry I see an audit entry (event ID 4657) for that change, **but** when I change the IP address using the properties of the network adapter or using the `netsh` command no audit on the setting of the new IP address is written to the event log.

Why the change does not appear in the event viewer log?

I tried it on Windows 7 and Windows 2012.